# Kernel error in Jupyter with cling

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, jupyter-notebook, cling

I have this problem. When I launch a c++17 notebook in jupyter, I get the kernel error. However, python3 notebook is working fine.

I build cling as per the instructions given in https://github.com/root-project/cling

From the trace it is clear that some file is missing but which one, that's unclear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

[image]

Comment: It's been ~a year, on Ubuntu 16.04 I experience the same error. Any solution?